# Woocommerce - how to show current user's orders on the custom page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to show users order list with my own html and css, like the number and the thumbnail in the left part of the item, and in the right part it has to be an order date, an order status, the quantity and the price, and my own meta.
I've founded how to add an image with the hook, it's not a problem. The problem is  - that I can't customize the native structure of woocommerce/myaccount/orders.php. Even when I change table, tr,td,tbody to div-s, my wrappers don't help. It's a loop. And all that I add is adding for all items

```
foreach ( $customer_orders->orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                ?>
                <div class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_atdiv( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <div class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_atdiv( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_atdiv( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_atdiv( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* divanslators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endforeach;
```

I need to separate the order-number and the added thumbnail to one wrapper, and all other metas to another.
I need something like global $product; product-> get_price(); but with the order.
Maybe there is some hooks of functions to display all order parts separately, and make a new loop?

Answer (score 1):

As per our understanding, you want to create your own template page and show current user orders.
If I am right you should try like this:

```
<?php
/*
* Template Name: Order Page Template
*/

defined( 'ABSPATH' ) || exit;

global $woocommerce, $user_id;  

if (!class_exists('WooCommerce') || !get_current_user_id()) {
    return;
};

$user_id = get_current_user_id();

//$customer = wp_get_current_user();
$posts_per_page = 20; 
// Get all customer orders
$customer__all_orders = get_posts(apply_filters('woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_query', array(
    'numberposts' => -1,
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'orderby' => 'date',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_value' => $user_id ,
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types(),
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()), 'post_status' => array('wc-processing'),
)));
$paged = isset($_REQUEST['order_page']) ? $_REQUEST['order_page'] : 1;
$total_records = count($customer__all_orders);
$total_pages = ceil($total_records / $posts_per_page);


$customer_orders = get_posts(array(
    'meta_key' => '_customer_user',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    'meta_value' => $user_id ,
    'post_type' => wc_get_order_types(),
    'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'post_status' => array_keys(wc_get_order_statuses()), 'post_status' => array('wc-processing'),
));
?>


<?php if (!empty($customer_orders)) : ?>

    <table class="woocommerce-orders-table woocommerce-MyAccount-orders shop_table shop_table_responsive my_account_orders account-orders-table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                    <th class="woocommerce-orders-table__header woocommerce-orders-table__header-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>"><span class="nobr"><?php echo esc_html( $column_name ); ?></span></th>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach ( $customer_orders as $customer_order ) {
                $order      = wc_get_order( $customer_order ); 
                $item_count = $order->get_item_count() - $order->get_item_count_refunded();
                ?>
                <tr class="woocommerce-orders-table__row woocommerce-orders-table__row--status-<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_status() ); ?> order">
                    <?php foreach ( wc_get_account_orders_columns() as $column_id => $column_name ) : ?>
                        <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-<?php echo esc_attr( $column_id ); ?>" data-title="<?php echo esc_attr( $column_name ); ?>">
                            <?php if ( has_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id ) ) : ?>
                                <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_my_account_my_orders_column_' . $column_id, $order ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-number' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo esc_url( $order->get_view_order_url() ); ?>">
                                    <?php echo esc_html( _x( '#', 'hash before order number', 'woocommerce' ) . $order->get_order_number() ); ?>
                                </a>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-date' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <time datetime="<?php echo esc_attr( $order->get_date_created()->date( 'c' ) ); ?>"><?php echo esc_html( wc_format_datetime( $order->get_date_created() ) ); ?></time>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-status' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php echo esc_html( wc_get_order_status_name( $order->get_status() ) ); ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-total' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                /* translators: 1: formatted order total 2: total order items */
                                echo wp_kses_post( sprintf( _n( '%1$s for %2$s item', '%1$s for %2$s items', $item_count, 'woocommerce' ), $order->get_formatted_order_total(), $item_count ) );
                                ?>

                            <?php elseif ( 'order-actions' === $column_id ) : ?>
                                <?php
                                $actions = wc_get_account_orders_actions( $order );

                                if ( ! empty( $actions ) ) {
                                    foreach ( $actions as $key => $action ) { // phpcs:ignore WordPress.WP.GlobalVariablesOverride.Prohibited
                                        echo '<a href="' . esc_url( $action['url'] ) . '" class="woocommerce-button button ' . sanitize_html_class( $key ) . '">' . esc_html( $action['name'] ) . '</a>';
                                    }
                                }
                                ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </td>
                    <?php endforeach; ?>
                </tr>
                <?php
            }
            ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
    <div class="pagination">
    <?php
        $args = array(
            'base' => '%_%',
            'format' => '?order_page=%#%',
            'total' => $total_pages,
            'current' => $paged,
            'show_all' => False,
            'end_size' => 5,
            'mid_size' => 5,
            'prev_next' => True,
            'prev_text' => __('&laquo; Previous'),
            'next_text' => __('Next &raquo;'),
            'type' => 'plain',
            'add_args' => False,
            'add_fragment' => ''
        );
        echo paginate_links($args);
    ?>
</div>
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="woocommerce-message woocommerce-message--info woocommerce-Message woocommerce-Message--info woocommerce-info">
        <a class="woocommerce-Button button" href="<?php echo esc_url( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_return_to_shop_redirect', wc_get_page_permalink( 'shop' ) ) ); ?>"><?php esc_html_e( 'Browse products', 'woocommerce' ); ?></a>
        <?php esc_html_e( 'No order has been made yet.', 'woocommerce' ); ?>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

**Steps:**

1. Create new page inside your active theme - template-order.php
2. Copy past above code inside your template-order.php apge and save.
3. Goto wordpress admin dashboard pages menu and click on new page
4. After create new page assign templete "Order Page Templete" and save
5. Now open your new page and you will get or order related to current logged in user

**Note:** You can also modify above code accordingly

Comment: But it's the same non-convenient table, I need the value from it, but to place them in my own html flex tags

Comment: You can change css and html according to your theme layout